# Conect DB Class Crud Errorrr

Tags: php

I'm problem in php archivo.

```
 ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\Apache24\htdocs\models\ClassCrud.php on line 11
( ! ) Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\Apache24\htdocs\models\ClassCrud.php on line 11
```

My codig conxeao.php

`abstract class ClassConexao{

```
protected function conectaDB()
{
    try{
        $con=new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sistema","root","123456");
        return $con;
    }catch (\PDOException $erro){
        return $erro->getMessage();
    }
}
```

}

`

I'need help. Thanks

Comment: It seems like you are getting an error from your connection and you are returning the error message which may be a string, try throwing an exception. The prepare() function must be getting the error message string.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function name. Try this:

```
protected function connectsDB()
{
    try {
        $con = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sistema", "root", "123456");
        return $con;
    } catch (\PDOException $error) {
        return $error->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this resolve the issue `Call to a member function prepare() on string`?